# Obtaining information from a DAT file

Tags: php, multithreading, binary

I would like to know if there is a way in php to read the info contained in a dat file ?.
The content of the file, if you open it with an editor, is the following:

```
0000 0000 0002 0091 0000 0091 0000 744f
7053 0000 0000 00e0 8100 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0200 0000
0b00 0000 1000 0000 4d00 0000 6b00 0000
7f00 0000 8f00 0000 8f00 0000 8f00 0000
8f00 0000 8f00 0000 8f00 0000 8f00 0000
8f00 0000 8f00 0000 8f00 0000 8f00 0000
8f00 0000 8f00 0000 8f00 0000 8f00 0000
8f00 0000 8f00 0000 8f00 0000 8f00 0000
8f00 0000 8f00 0000 8f00 0000 8f00 0000
8f00 0000 8f00 0000 8f00 0000 8f00 0000
8f00 0000 8f00 0000 8f00 0000 8f00 0000
8f00 0000 8f00 0000 8f00 0000 8f00 0000
8f00 0000 8f00 0000 8f00 0000 8f00 0000
8f00 0000 8f00 0000 8f00 0000 8f00 0000
8f00 0000 8f00 0000 8f00 0000 8f00 0000
8f00 0000 8f00 0000 8f00 0000 8f00 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0200 0000 0b00 0000
```

An so on... The thing is that I have read some lines and seen some info but it's full of strange symbols... Is there a way or special config to read ?.

The code I used is:

```
<?php
   //Storing the previous encoding in case you have some other piece 
   //of code sensitive to encoding and counting on the default value.      
   $previous_encoding = mb_internal_encoding();

   //Set the encoding to UTF-8, so when reading files it ignores the BOM       
   mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

   //Process the CSS files...

   //Finally, return to the previous encoding
   mb_internal_encoding($previous_encoding);

   //Rest of the code...
// Provee.Dat
$data = fopen('Provee.Dat', "rb");
while(!feof($data)) {
  echo preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', fgets($data)) . "<br>";
}
fclose($data);
?>
```